# SQL Query (conditional)

Tags: sql

I'm trying to query from an SQL table. I am having issues getting an if statement to work for a conditional thing I'm trying to achieve in the query.

If the deaths of the player = 0, I want the kd column (ratio) to be equal to kills, not NULL. Here is my current query, I have no clue how to take this.

```
SELECT name, time, map, kills, deaths, kills/deaths AS kd 
FROM history;
```

Logic I want:

- if deaths = 0: kills/deaths = kills

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT name, time, map, kills, deaths,
       (case when deaths = 0 then kills else kills/deaths end) as kd 
FROM history;
```

Normally, to avoid divide by zero, it is sufficient for the result to be `NULL`.  If this is what you really want, then `NULLIF()` is a better solution:

```
SELECT name, time, map, kills, deaths,
       ( kills / NULLIF(deaths, 0) ) as kd 
FROM history;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The case expression was exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a WHERE clause you know.

And to make better statements when you insert in your database.